# Getting started with $inject

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to follow [John Papa's Angular styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) for writing an angular app, but dependency injection is not working for me like this. ShopController and dataservice both have dependencies, but I'm always running into a `"cannot read property ____ of undefined"` no matter what I try.

```
angular
    .module('shopApp', []);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

angular
    .module('shopApp')
    .controller('ShopController', ShopController);

ShopController.$inject['dataservice'];

function ShopController(dataservice){
    var vm = this;
    vm.products = [];
    vm.getProducts = getProducts;
    vm.title = 'test title';

    activate();

    function activate() {
        return getProducts().then(function() {
            console.info('Got Products');
        });
    }

    function getProducts() {
        return dataservice.getProducts().then(function(data) {
            vm.products = data;
            console.info(data);
            return vm.products;
        });
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


angular
    .module('shopApp')
    .factory('dataservice', dataservice);

dataservice.$inject = ['$http'];

function dataservice($http) {
    return {
        getProducts: getProducts
    };

    function getProducts() {
        return $http.get('/api/products')
            .then(getProductsComplete)
            .catch(getProductsFailed);

        function getProductsComplete(response) {
            return response.data.results;
        }

        function getProductsFailed(error) {
            console.error('XHR Failed for getProducts.' + error.data);
        }
    }
}
```

The approach does *look* much cleaner, but I'm puzzled why it's not working properly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
ShopController.$inject['dataservice'];
```

by

```
ShopController.$inject = ['dataservice'];
```

Comment: Wow, it was staring back at me this whole time! Won't make that mistake again :)